# How do I preview a map within a node-based material?

Tags: materials, interface

I'm in the material editor and I can see the preview window on the right showing me the final result of my material.  However, I'd like to preview individual texture maps **or** preview a certain position within the node graph.  In the image below, how would I get a preview of that Musgrave texture?

[image: How would I get a preview of that Musgrave texture?]

e.g. [In the 3dsMax Compact Material Editor](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/3DSMax-Lighting-Shading/images/GUID-3EA00908-0301-4257-ADBF-214507EA55AA.png) You can select "Show final" (3rd icon from the right below the material slots) and see the final material or you can turn it off and preview the thing you're currently editing.

Thanks!

Comment: The Node Wrangler addon will do exactly what you're looking for.   http://gregzaal.github.io/node-wrangler/   Ctrl-Shift-Click on most nodes will show you the output of the particular node, just like in the compositor.  Lots of other benefits as well.

Comment: *Node Wrangler Addon* is shipped with Blender by default. Just go to *File > User Preferences > Add-ons* and search for "Node..."

Comment: Great suggestions, though I'm not a fan of Node Wrangler cutting node connections in order to do it.  That seems like a hack; surely there's a way for Blender to do this as-is and elegantly?  Right?  